# choose a video not from default direction, error with audio

Tags: matlab, audio, video-processing

i choose a video from a other folder (not from default )
the problem is when i want to make a audio of this video it give me a Error beacouse he search for this filename in the default

```
[filename,dic] = uigetfile('*.mp4','Select the MATLAB code file');

[y,Fs] = audioread(filename );
audiowrite('sound.mp4',y,Fs);
```

the error

```
**Error using audioread (line 74)
The filename specified was not found in the MATLAB path.

Error in final (line 6)
[y,Fs] = audioread(filename );**
```

what i need to do for Solve the problem?

Comment: Can't you specify an absolute path? Like e.g. (if you're on Windows) c:\yourFolder\Yoursoundfile.mp4 or add the folder that the soundfile to the paths that matlab searches in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second output of `uigetfile` should be the path (directory where the file name is), and you should be able to put these outputs directly into the function `fullfile`:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread(fullfile(dic,filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the absolute path instead of only the relative path solved my problem.

Comment: this is an old question that has an accepted answer, if you don't have something new to add, please don't post an answer.
The problem in the question is about getting a file path using `uigetfile`, so what is the absolute path in that context? do you mean `[dic, filename]`?